# bash: ./mono: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, mono

I downloaded something off the internet for my ubu12.04x86 and whenever i cd to that directory and try ./mono is gives me

```
bash: ./mono: No such file or directory
```

mono is a type of .net->deb container for aplications allowing some programs to run on linux that were made for windows

also even though i have set Allow executing file as program, when i double click it doesnt ask me whether to display cancel run or runterminal option

why?

Comment: Can you  `cd` to that folder and run `ls -l`?

Comment: Have you installed mono?

Comment: after ls -l it gives me the files, one of wich is:    "-rwxrwxrwx 1 thenok thenok 2629092 Sep 14  2010 mono"

Comment: i have tried to install mono, but that doesnt change the fact that i need to run this script not the program from ubuntu software center

Answer (score 2):

Either mono is not in that directory or it is not executable.  If it is not in that directory, use either of these commands to find it:

```
whereis mono

updatedb; locate mono
```

If it is in that directory, run:

```
chmod +x ./mono
```

and try again.

Comment: whereis mono -> "mono: "

Comment: updatedb; locate mono -> shows a lot of files and folder, most are "/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/*"

Comment: did i forgot to mention that i already chmod-ed it? ; chmod gave no error, but running it afterwards proved the same no such file